# Find the name of an instance of a class from within the class

Tags: python, class, module

If I had this Python script:

```
class my_class(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_name(self):
        return [name of self]


this_is_the_name_im_looking_for = my_class()

print ('the name is: ' + this_is_the_name_im_looking_for.get_name())
```

What would I have to replace *[name of self]* with in order to have the function *get_name* to return 'this_is_the_name_im_looking_for'?

I need this because I'm creating a Python module and want to feed back which instance of this class they're using

Comment: A single instance of your class may be bound to multiple variable names: `this_name = my_class(); other_name = this_name; this_name is other_name == True`

Comment: @ali_m I'm basing the question on the assumption that this is not the case, but that's a helpful comment nonetheless

Comment: Or, it might have no name at all: `mylist.append(my_class())`.

Comment: Why call a method, when you already have to type the name  (if there is one) of the instance in order to call the method. Not clear why you need this

Comment: Your instance may also be named differently depending on the scope you're in, e.g. if it's passed as an input to a function it's name within the scope of the function will be the name of the argument. Can you explain why you think you need the variable name?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye In the actual context, the function isn't just to return the name, however I would like to use the name in parts of the function

Comment: Why not make the name an attribute of the instance, e.g. `def __init__(self, name); self.name = name`?

Comment: There might be a way to do this using the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module, but I can't really think of a good reason why you'd want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in python method `id` [returns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)

> an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime.

This doesn't return the 'name' of the object per-se, but it will allow you to distinguish between different instances of the class.  This also solves the problem of having multiple pointers to the same object since the id is associated with the underlying object (the address of the object in memory):

```
val1 = 1
val2 = val1
id(val1) == id(val2)
# returns: True
id(val1) == id(1)
# returns: True
id(val1) == id(2)
# returns: False
```

Comment: I think he wants `get_name(val1) != get_name(val2)`.

Comment: Be careful using int with id as examples you get surprising results. id(100*1000) is not the same as id (1000*100) but the int passed id is the value value.